# Display Business phone number Google Maps Android Studio Kotlin

Tags: android-studio, phone-number, google-nearby

I am trying to create a map on Android Studio in Kotlin that shows nearby places of certain searches. For example, I want to show nearby police stations along with their address and phone number. When I try to display a phone number of a business when the user selects the pin of the business, it only displays the business name and address and states that the phone number is empty. But if I pull up the same business on google maps it shows the phone number and more information such as the website and hours.

I cannot figure out why the phone number is not being displayed...

```
    private fun showNearbyPoliceStations() {
    val policeStationUrl = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?" +
            "location=$latitute,$longitude&radius=5000&type=police&keyword=police%20department&key=MYAPI"


    val client = OkHttpClient()
    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(policeStationUrl)
        .build()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object : okhttp3.Callback {
        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            // Handle error
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val jsonData = response.body?.string()
            if (jsonData != null) {
                val jsonObject = JSONObject(jsonData)
                val results = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results")

                runOnUiThread {
                    for (i in 0 until results.length()) {
                        val policeStation = results.getJSONObject(i)
                        val geometry = policeStation.getJSONObject("geometry")
                        val location = geometry.getJSONObject("location")
                        val lat = location.getDouble("lat")
                        val lng = location.getDouble("lng")
                        val name = policeStation.getString("name")
                        val address = policeStation.optString("vicinity") // Get address
                        val phoneNumber = policeStation.optString("formatted_phone_number") // Get phone number

                        val latLng = LatLng(lat, lng)
                        val markerOptions = MarkerOptions()
                            .position(latLng)
                            .title(name)
                            .snippet("Address: $address \nPhone: $phoneNumber") // Add snippet with address and phone number
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_BLUE))

                        mMap?.addMarker(markerOptions)
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    })
}
```